# Is there any plugin available to highlight the matched search text in Terminator?

Tags: search, terminator

I would like to search from the `tail` result in my current tab. Terminator provides option to search for certain text - but since it's not highlighting the matched text not able to find it easily.

Is there any plugin available which I can include to Terminator which can help me to highlight the matched search result.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 4):

NEWS:
termintor was change mantainer at 2020-11,
terminator 2.1.1 (from new ppa) got search highlight now

### old repo

https://launchpad.net/terminator/
// read-only, seems no new release anymore.

### new repo

https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator
https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/INSTALL.md

install from new ppa // ref: github INSTALL.md

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install terminator
```

// ubuntu 20.04 apt still old version 1.9.x.

#### terminator 2.1.1 got search highlight

[image: terminator_search_hightlight.png]

NOTE:
`terminator -u` will make sure run GUI in new process
rather than create new window in old process (through DBus).

Comment: Ok, this only highlights _one_ location, and you have to use the buttons to skip to the next/previous one. Is there a way to highlight _all_ locations, like in Konsole, Firefox and some other applications?

Comment: @rob74 sometimes I wanna it too, I didn't found yet. I will check the source code when I have time

Answer (score 1):

What you want isn't yet a built-in feature but is slated for a future release.

From [here](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#search-the-buffer)

> It is possible to search the buffer, although at this time there is a limitation that the found string is not highlighted.

and

> At this time there is no highlighting of the search string. This is a historical limitation due to the manner in which the implmentation was originally done, way back when. I intend to remove the old code, replacing with the built-in libvte search function in the 2.1 release. This will then highlight searched text.

Neither [this page](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) nor [this page](https://launchpad.net/~gnome-terminator/+archive/ubuntu/nightly-gtk3) point to the 2.1 release.

And according to [this page](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#plugins), there doesn't seem to be a plugin to provide the feature.

---

You could maybe consider using something else such as `gnome-terminal` if this feature is important to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue on Terminator Github:

https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/4

Also on launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/+bug/271487

It is supposed to be released on 2.1 milestone:

https://launchpad.net/terminator/+milestone/2.1

There is no expected release date yet :(